# Charting errors in NewRelic

Tags: newrelic

Is it possible to have the Errors charterd as count/time instead of per request for a NewRelic non-IIS app?

There's a table below the chart showing the total count and I wonder if we can see a type of chart using that value instead of using the request as the scope.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Eventually charting the number of errors per time didn't work and got a confirmation from NewRelic for this, I had to create a custom metric and to increment it each time my exception was thrown (using IncrementCounter from NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic)